# Can anyone please recommend any good Load Testing software?

Tags: load-testing

Can anyone please recommend any good Load Testing software?

I have a website which updates scores every minute via ajax calls and need a load testing software which supports ajax calls (javascript) too!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530891/tools-for-ajax-load-testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question that depends greatly on exactly what you want to test and how you define "good" software. Many people will say you can't load test AJAX based sites using HTTP-simulation tools. We do it every day, so I can tell you that isn't true. However, the difficulty of the task varies greatly depending on the testing software you choose and the complexity of the site and scenarios you are testing.

My recommendation is to pick a few tools within your price range and evaluate how well they work for your particular scenario. If they have good support, you should contact them with any difficulties. If they can't get you going in short order, move on to the next product.

(Disclaimer: I work for Web Performance - our Load Tester product handles most AJAX scenarios just fine - which may be why we're on the first google page for "ajax load testing").

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is just an HTTP call, so you have many options.

I can recommend [WebLOAD](http://www.radview.com/solutions/ajax-load-testing.aspx). 
Works well with Ajax. The script is written in JavaScript, which is a plus.

Answer (score 0):

Although I cant recommend an AJAX load testing utility I can however recommend an alternative to normal AJAX calls to me it sounds like what you need is APE (Ajax Push Engine).

So instead if your application spawn repeatedly contacting the server

> Your App -> Do you have a message for me server?..
>
> Server -> No..
>
> repeat X 10 Ajax Calls until Server -> Yes!

What APE does it pushes the data/information directly to your users browser without
the application contacting the server. Think of it this way, the server "shouts" a message and your web apps then receive this message and interprets it. This concepts is known as long polling.

APE is pretty darn fast and not that difficult to implement.
Heres a link to the APE project - http://ape-project.org

Theres a few guys that have some excellent examples available on the Internet,
heres a link to an interesting one which uses APE to create an SMS gateway.
http://www.ifc0nfig.com/esenape-send-and-receive-sms-in-real-time-using-ape-jquery-php-and-libape_controller/

I hope this interests you.

Regards